# Change 24 hour clock to 12 hour for created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Does someone know how to change the rails default 24 hour format to a 12 hour format?

```
<%=h message.created_at.to_s(:long) %>
```

The format is showing as December 05, 2013 13:39 currently. The correct format should be December 05, 2013 1:39PM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up `strftime` (for any language), and build the actual template yourself. Per `Time::DATE_FORMATS`, the offending template is `'%B %d, %Y %H:%M'`, so change the end to `%I:%M %p`.

(You also might want to add a new format to `DATE_FORMATS`...)

Comment: Thank you. I had something like it before but it wasn't working but I noticed my error. Thanks for referencing me back to `strftime`. Code that worked is `.created_at.strftime('%B %-d, %Y %l:%M%P') `

Comment: Why does everyone go `%l:%M%P`? I noticed that also in a project I took over. Typographically it should be `%l:%M %P`.